# Is there any difference between Loan and Credit?

Tags: finance

We are drafting a formal document. I saw somebody replace all occurrences of the word *credit* to *loan*. There is no specific meaning assigned to either of these words within the document.

Is there any difference between these? I was using them interchangeably.

**EDIT: (Some examples due to massive downvote)**

- The interest rate to be applied to the **loans/credits** shall be
  determined.
- For **credits/loans** disbursed in any foreign currency...
- In the event the Client uses the **loan/credit** from the Bank's branches outside Germany...

Comment: Please edit question and include the core parts of a couple of examples from the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience as an economist, I would say that extending credit to someone grants them the *ability* to borrow, while a loan is actually the *act* of borrowing. If a bank gives me a $500 line of credit, I can, at some date in the future when I want to, borrow money from them. If a bank gives me a $500 loan, I take possession of them money today.

Comment: Hi, but getting a loan merely signifies the loan being sanctioned on our name right? and then it depends on us when do we actually use the loan or not use the loan at all?
So if a bank gives me a loan of $500, that means the bank has sanctioned me to borrow $500 from them, and I can withdraw that amount using a check or transfer to my actual account or by other means. But If I choose, I don't even have to actually ever touch that sanctioned money. right?

Comment: getting approved for a loan, yes, but *getting* a loan means you actually receive the money. Getting credit, on the other hand, is more like getting *approved* for a loan.

Comment: Thats better.
Here is another source to support you:
http://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/loan.asp

Answer (score 1):

When talking in financial terms, a loan is usually followed by an interest on the amount unlike credit, which might or might not be followed by an interest.

[Definition of credit 1 [mass noun]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/credit?q=credit)

> the ability of a customer to obtain
>   goods or services before payment, based on the trust that payment will
>   be made in the future.

[Definition of loan [noun]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/loan?q=loan)

> a thing that is borrowed, especially a sum of money that is expected
>   to be paid back with interest

Comment: Please include source of defs in your answer – preferably links to specific entries instead of generic, eg  *[loan](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/loan?q=loan)* instead of [oxforddictionaries.com](http://oxforddictionaries.com/)

Comment: sorry forgot to mention the sources, just edited em in.
Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @camelbrush Please link to the actual definitions rather than to the dictionary's homepage.

Comment: added links to the words' definitions.